# Android Studio очередность выполнения методов

Tags: java, android

Взял LoginActivity которая стандартно есть в Android.
Есть метод, в котором происходит проверка авторизации пользователя.
то Есть ,я передаю логин и пароль, в метод checkAuth, который по сокету проверяет совпадение в базе данных и возвращает значение gui для конкретного пользователя. Но у меня каждый раз срабатывает else, т.к. проверка  `if(gui.equals("admin"))` происходит еще до того, как от сервера пришел ответ. Как такое может быть?
разве не должна программа дождаться результата gui, прежде чем идти дальше?

```
 public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {

 String gui = checkAuth(username, password);


 if(gui.equals("admin")) {
try {
    // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication


    LoggedInUser fakeUser =
            new LoggedInUser(
                    java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                    "Jane Doe");

    return new Result.Success<>(fakeUser);

} catch (Exception e) {
    return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
}
 } else {
        return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Как выглядит `checkAuth`? Там же наверно асинхронная задача?

Comment: @RomanKonoval там целая ветвь методов из него выходит, где происходит создание соединения с сокет сервером, отправка запроса и ожидание ответа

Comment: Не зная, что там, невозможно дать объективный ответ - можно только гадать и предполагать.

Comment: @RomanKonoval вы были правы, недосмотрел, сокет соединение в отдельном потоке стартовало, в общем натупил) спасибо за подсказку